# LED Breathing Effect

Tags: led, c, pwm

Please consider the following code:

```
for(;;)
{
 int i=0;  
 TPM1C2VL  =~ (i<<1); // Channel Value(Lower)Register.
 TPM1C2VH +=TPM1C2VL; 
}
```

**ALTERED CODE**

```
unsigned long duty[420] = {<from zero to 65535>}

for(i = 0; i != 420; i++ )
   {
  TPM1C2VL =~ duty[i];
  TPM1C2VH += TPM1C2VL;
}
for( ; i != 0; i-- )
{
  TPM1C2VL =~ duty[i];
  TPM1C2VH += TPM1C2VL;
}
```

**After the alteration also, there is no effective change, as now the LED just blinks randomly**

I just wanted to apply breathing effect on a LED. Just to test I wrote the code with basic intuition of how it is supposed to work, didnt expect it to work in one shot, but it does.

Now my question is, HOW TO REVERSE THIS EFFECT? i.e. Slowly the LED dies out to zero. 
I am not able to induce a reversal of this effect. I am using PWM of [MC9S08DZ60](http://www.freescale.com/files/microcontrollers/doc/data_sheet/MC9S08DZ60.pdf).
I have made the following settings:
Prescaler = 1.

Modulo Counter = 65535.

Period = 4.096ms.

Edge Aligned.

On Channel 1.

PWM:
Set OUtput on Compare.

Channel Duty = 4.095ms.

Comment: TO ALL: Just to clarify, The led glows untill fully bright and immediately dies out and starts again. I need to Slow down the die out process and start again.

Comment: Effectively, this loop subtracts 255 from the 16-bit register pair (in line 5) til it reaches zero and underflows to 0xFFFF, continuously. This is probably not what you intended. Line 3 is redundant; it just keeps setting i to 0. Line 4 is redundant; it always sets TPM1C2VL to 0xFF. If you meant for the loop to manipulate 'i' in some way, that isn't happening. I'm not clear what you meant `TPM1C2VL =~ (i<<1);` to do; if it was was to slowly increase the 16-bit register's contents to 0xFF and then slowly decrease it to 0, it doesn't do that.

Comment: @JRobert: THank you robert. SOmething i wasnt able to express due to my lack of experience. SO, should i stick to an array of log values divided on logarithmic scale until 255? or stick to the same as written above with modification.
SORRY for not messaging earlier, was sick and out for last two days!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sample code that should get you started.  You could implement the full 0 -> 65535 -> 0 16-bit count, but since your code only counts by 256 and seems to make half of the ramp you're looking for, I have done likewise.

It might be fun to write another experiment that picks log or other values from a table to see how the appearance changes, but if all you want is a simple ramp up and ramp down, something like this should do it.

```
TPM1C2VL = 0;       // not modifying the ...VL register, just zero it
for(;;){
   int i;

   // Up counter
   for(i = 0; i != 256; ++i ){
  TPM1C2VH = i;
  ;  // maybe some delay here
   }

   // Down counter
   for( ; i != 0; --i ){
  TPM1C2VH = i;
  ;  // maybe some delay here
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate! I wrote some similar but without FOR loop,will only be able to try it on monday. please let me get back to you then!

Comment: Mate i have updated the question. I hope i can get some input!

Comment: `TPM1C2VH += TPM1C2VL;` adds the complemented duty-cycle to the ...H register; should it?  Sorry my code didn't help - I'm not familiar with this device's PWM and a quick read of the data sheet didn't help me much. Since your own code worked better go back that for starters, but you will need a count-up / count-down sequence in your code. (Continued....)

Comment: ... Can you find some sample PWM code for this device? My search only turned up your two questions. Perhaps Freescale will have a PWM application note for the chip. Start with any known working code and tweak it in little steps til you understand more about how to use the timer/PWM registers.

Comment: Hi! Would it make a difference if i changed from EDGE ALIGNED to CENTER ALIGNED? thereby, re-writing my code?

Comment: I doubt it but I could only guess. Double check how you program the device's PWM registers: bit assignments, set up sequence, maybe even setup timing. There's a [discussion about PWM setup](https://community.freescale.com/thread/38787) on the Freescale website - you may find some answers there.

Comment: THanks for the info! I have been using the same method as given in the link. But i am still lost! It just keeps blinking randomly! i will restart, re-learn. If any suggestions do come along you mind, Please fwd them. I will keep this page open.

Answer (score 3):

You need to do two things - the first is make it fade out. The brightness of the LED is determined by the value in the TPM1C2VH register. by changing TPM1C2VH you are changing the brightness. In order to decrease the brightness, you need to switch around the direction so that you're counting in the opposite direction.

The second bit you need to do is detect when you are increasing and when you are decreasing. You need something like an if statement, like so:

```
if (TPM1C2VH >= max_threshold)
  // decrease TPM1C2VH
else if (TPM1C2VH <= min_threshold)
  // increase TPM1C2VH
```

Combine these two, and you have your breathing LED.